# How to restrict user from register anonymously in my ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity framework. Everything is ok, but I want to restrict user register anonymously in the application, so that only logged-in user can create other users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually it is a basic question. You will have to understand how authenticaton and authorization works in ASP.NET Core Identity then you can work forward and create your own custom features. Check [this tutorial](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-authentication/) to understand how Identity works.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions, probably not the best option, but they work.

The First:
Before calling `Register`, first determine whether the user is logged in.

For example:

Determine whether to call `Register` by judging whether `userName` is null.

```
var userName = _userManager.GetUserName(HttpContext.User);
if (userName != null)
{ 
     //Register
}
```

The Second:

Cancel Register button, load this button after login.

Of course, if you have a deep enough understanding of identity, perhaps [RoleManager](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-roles/) is a better choice.